# kubectl connection issues on Ubuntu 22.04LTS with Kubernetes 1.26.0

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, haproxy

I have installed `kubeadm`, `kubelet` and `kubectl` using `sudo apt install` command, and they are all version `1.26.0`. I use Ubuntu 22.04LTS machine. I just wanted to test and use Kubernetes on my local computer. But I don't know why I get the following error messages whenever I try `kubectl` commands like `kubelctl get pods/nodes/etc`:

```
kubectl get pods
E1212 08:13:11.758898    4321 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.2:6443: connect: connection refused
E1212 08:13:11.759479    4321 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.2:6443: connect: connection refused
E1212 08:13:11.761197    4321 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.2:6443: connect: connection refused
E1212 08:13:11.762636    4321 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.2:6443: connect: connection refused
E1212 08:13:11.764083    4321 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.2:6443: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server 192.168.1.2:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I don't know why I get this error message.

Comment: `kubectl` is a client-side tool that connects to the API server in a K8s cluster. It's trying to connect to some default address for that API server here, and is not able to find it. Do you know the address to your K8s API server?

Comment: @Haxiel: No! Actually I don't know if `kubeadm` creates a default server or not? I don't have any other machine as an external server. I just want to run Kubernetes( both client and server) on my local machine, like what a `Docker-Desktop` do on Windows or Mac.

Comment: You can use `kubeadm` to quickly set up a cluster; that's the purpose of that tool. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Comment: @Haxiel: Thank you! I didn't know that I must create a cluster by myself. Because I have seen `master-node` in configuration files and thought maybe this is the default cluster that `kubeadm` automatically creates while `apt install kubeadm`, or `kubeadm init` procedure.

Answer (score -1):

If your runtime is docker and you use minikube, then you should consider running:

```
minikube delete
open -a docker
minikube start --driver=docker
kubectl get pods
```

This worked for me.